# Sql script to search value in column of database by taking value from a file

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a csv file with two columns. The file has over 200.000 rows. Inside database I have the same table with the same values.

How can I write a script so that I can search for the values that are present in file but not in database?

I am using SQL Developer for this

Comment: I would create an external table that uses the file, then join the real table and the external table

Comment: Cant create new tables

Comment: You could also export the table to a csv and then compare the 2 csv files using `diff` or text comparison tools.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an External table is the best option when you want to read the contents of a flat-file using a select query.

Click [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i) to know more about how to create an external table.

After creating the external table, you can make use of a query similar to below to identify the records which are exclusively available in the external table(i.e. flat file).

```
select *
from new_external_table et
where not exists (select 1 from source_table st where et.column_name=st.column_name);
```